# Play BrightCove video when clicking link

Tags: jquery, brightcove

I have implemented Brightcove video into a mobile site and I'd like to play the video when the user clicks a link, is there a way of accessing the video and initiating it with JQuery?

```
 <div id="video_player"><!-- brightcove player goes here --></div>
        <script>
            BCL.addPlayer('video_player', '2102405248001');<!-- 'id' of target div, Brightcove Asset ID -->
        </script>
        <a href="#" class="play"></a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the `BCL.addPlayer` function to a click on the anchor tag.

Note: I've used the jQuery `.one` method here to prevent the player being initialized over and over again when the `play` anchor is clicked.

```
$('a.play').one('click', function(){
    BCL.addPlayer('video_player', '2102405248001');
});
```

Comment: thanks, but when I try that on my iphone it says, the video you are trying to watch is not compatible with this device

Comment: That a different issue altogether - as the error suggests, the video may be incompatible for the device you're trying to play it on, an unsupported format maybe?

Comment: your code just adds the player, it doesn't initialise it, is there a command to play the video not just add it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Brightcove API. You'll probably need to dig into it - http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/dynamically-loading-player-using-javascript

Comment: Inside of a PhoneGap app, I'm also getting that same error on on a Galaxy S4.  Not on my Nexus 4 or 5 though.  The full error is as follows:

`D/CordovaLog( 3367): http://qa.efacts.enbridgedev.net/Video.aspx?video-id=3006144194001&background-color=76b900: Line 67 : Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
E/Web Console( 3367): Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor:67
D/VideoLayerManager( 3367): Reinit GLResource for VideoLayer
V/chromium_net( 3367): external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:419: [0422/121638:INFO:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(419)] ~SSLClientSocketOpenSSL()`